# angularjs filter to function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I found this filter https://gist.github.com/Cacodaimon/7309268 sumByKey which works great and calculates summaries by any given key.

```
demo.filter('sumByKey', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += parseInt(data[i][key]);
    }

    return sum;
   };
})
```

How can I make this filter to a function ie:

```
$scope.getTotal = function(key){
  // function of the filter here
}
```

the reason is that even though I can use the filter like this:

```
{{filtered|sumByKey:'quantity'}}
```

i cannot use it in a calculation like this:

```
 {{filtered|sumByKey:'quantity' * price}}
```

i could though use a function like this:

```
{{getTotal(quantity) * price}}
```

any ideas on how to either use the filter in the calculation or make the filter to function?

Comment: Any luck with any of these answers? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it infact, it is more of precedence issue. Just wrap filter result in brackets:-

```
{{(filtered|sumByKey:'quantity') * price}}
  ^__                        __^
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sxbvn8?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function in a filter:

> function(value): A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of array. The final result is an array of those elements that the predicate returned true for.

eg:

```
{{filtered|getTotal(quantity * price)}}
```

With your function taking the summed parameter:

```
$scope.total = 0;
$scope.getTotal = function(name) {
    return function(val) {
        total += val;
    }
}
```